# How to render the text like a all_sprites.update() but all_texts.update()?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a programm where i have a lot of text objects.

And i want to render it all by 1 command like a sprite.

For example:

```
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprite1 = mySprite([args])
sprite2 = mySprite([args])
all_sprite.add(sprite1, sprite2)
while True:
     all_sprites.update(([width, height]))
```

in the Class mySprite() we have a def update() what working with calling by Class Group()

I want to doo this operation not with sprites but with text. Can i did that by pygame instrumental? Or i want make this class (like a class Group()) by myself? If the second option, then how i can make it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rendered text is simply a `pygame.Surface` object. All you need to do is set the `image` attribute of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object with the rendered text surface and the `rect` attribute with the position of the text.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)

class Text(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, font, text, color, center_pos):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = font.render(text, True, color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center_pos)

all_text = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_text.add(Text(font, "Hello", "white", (200, 150)))
all_text.add(Text(font, "World!", "white", (200, 250)))

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    window.fill(0)
    all_text.draw(window)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! I really didn`t think that the text can be represented as a sprite...